# MXGraph JSON Graphs with Angular - render and read graph using JSON and ANGULAR with mxGraph

Tags: javascript, json, angular, workflow, mxgraph

I am trying to work with Angular and MX Graphs using JSON, I am sure that many of you also would think it is a great way to serialize graphs and also give them functionality within an angular application.

I have not been able to find a minimum example where a JSON representation of a graph is rendered from Angular.

Inn the demo part of this example with mxgraph using javascript, they simply render the graph from a json structure.

Example:
https://codepen.io/Gatcha/pen/oYexEB

JSON Structure

```
    {
        "graph": [
            {
                "value": {
                    "name": "Daffy Duck"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": 90,
                    "y": 60,
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 30,
                    "relative": false,
                    "TRANSLATE_CONTROL_POINTS": true,
                    "alternateBounds": null,
                    "sourcePoint": null,
                    "targetPoint": null,
                    "points": null,
                    "offset": null
                },
                "id": "2",
                "vertex": true,
                "connectable": true,
                "parent": "1",
                "source": null,
                "target": null,
                "edges": [
                    {
                        "value": "Edge",
                        "geometry": {
                            "x": 0,
                            "y": 0,
                            "width": 0,
                            "height": 0,
                            "relative": true
                        },
                        "id": "4",
                        "edge": true,
                        "parent": "1",
                        "source": "2",
                        "target": "3",
                        "mxObjectId": "mxCell#7"
                    }
                ],
                "mxObjectId": "mxCell#6"
            },
            {
                "value": {
                    "name": "Bugs Bunny"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": 1020,
                    "y": 60,
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 30,
                    "relative": false,
                    "TRANSLATE_CONTROL_POINTS": true,
                    "alternateBounds": null,
                    "sourcePoint": null,
                    "targetPoint": null,
                    "points": null,
                    "offset": null
                },
                "id": "3",
                "vertex": true,
                "connectable": true,
                "parent": "1",
                "source": null,
                "target": null,
                "edges": [
                    {
                        "value": "Edge",
                        "geometry": {
                            "x": 0,
                            "y": 0,
                            "width": 0,
                            "height": 0,
                            "relative": true
                        },
                        "id": "4",
                        "edge": true,
                        "parent": "1",
                        "source": "2",
                        "target": "3",
                        "mxObjectId": "mxCell#7"
                    }
                ],
                "mxObjectId": "mxCell#8"
            },
            {
                "value": "Edge",
                "geometry": {
                    "x": 0,
                    "y": 0,
                    "width": 0,
                    "height": 0,
                    "relative": true
                },
                "id": "4",
                "edge": true,
                "parent": "1",
                "source": "2",
                "target": "3",
                "mxObjectId": "mxCell#7"
            },
            {
                "value": {
                    "name": "Elmer Fudd"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": 90,
                    "y": 220,
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 30,
                    "relative": false,
                    "TRANSLATE_CONTROL_POINTS": true,
                    "alternateBounds": null,
                    "sourcePoint": null,
                    "targetPoint": null,
                    "points": null,
                    "offset": null
                },
                "id": "5",
                "vertex": true,
                "connectable": true,
                "parent": "1",
                "source": null,
                "target": null,
                "edges": [
                    {
                        "value": "Edge",
                        "geometry": {
                            "x": 0,
                            "y": 0,
                            "width": 0,
                            "height": 0,
                            "relative": true
                        },
                        "id": "7",
                        "edge": true,
                        "parent": "1",
                        "source": "5",
                        "target": "6",
                        "mxObjectId": "mxCell#10"
                    }
                ],
                "mxObjectId": "mxCell#9"
            },
            {
                "value": {
                    "name": "Tasmanian Devil"
                },
                "geometry": {
                    "x": 1020,
                    "y": 220,
                    "width": 120,
                    "height": 30,
                    "relative": false,
                    "TRANSLATE_CONTROL_POINTS": true,
                    "alternateBounds": null,
                    "sourcePoint": null,
                    "targetPoint": null,
                    "points": null,
                    "offset": null
                },
                "id": "6",
                "vertex": true,
                "connectable": true,
                "parent": "1",
                "source": null,
                "target": null,
                "edges": [
                    {
                        "value": "Edge",
                        "geometry": {
                            "x": 0,
                            "y": 0,
                            "width": 0,
                            "height": 0,
                            "relative": true
                        },
                        "id": "7",
                        "edge": true,
                        "parent": "1",
                        "source": "5",
                        "target": "6",
                        "mxObjectId": "mxCell#10"
                    }
                ],
                "mxObjectId": "mxCell#11"
            },
            {
                "value": "Edge",
                "geometry": {
                    "x": 0,
                    "y": 0,
                    "width": 0,
                    "height": 0,
                    "relative": true
                },
                "id": "7",
                "edge": true,
                "parent": "1",
                "source": "5",
                "target": "6",
                "mxObjectId": "mxCell#10"
            }
        ]
    }
```

and this is the Javascript code that renders the graph, where the json is obtained from a text area called "from" and pased to JSON, pretty basic and simple:

```
/******************************************************************
Demo
******************************************************************/

const graphX = new GraphX(document.getElementById('graphContainer'));

document.getElementById('buttons').appendChild(mxUtils.button('From JSON', () => {
  const dataModel = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('from').innerHTML);
  graphX.render(dataModel);
}));

document.getElementById('buttons').appendChild(mxUtils.button('To JSON', () => {
  const jsonNodes = graphX.getJsonModel();
  document.getElementById('to').innerHTML = `<pre>${syntaxHighlight(stringifyWithoutCircular(jsonNodes))}</pre>`;
}));
```

Does anyone have a little Idea of how to do this with Angular, in any way in order to start documenting this for everyone also?

Thanks a lot.
May the force be with you.

Note: There is the mxHierarchicalLayout.js class that i think would allow you to create a hierarchical model of the graph.

Here is the whole javascript file.

I will keep trying and post whatever I learn, but please if you have a hint, would be really apretiated.

```
/******************************************************************
Core
******************************************************************/

class JsonCodec extends mxObjectCodec {
    constructor() {
      super((value)=>{});
    }
    encode(value) {
        const xmlDoc = mxUtils.createXmlDocument();
        const newObject = xmlDoc.createElement("Object");
        for(let prop in value) {
          newObject.setAttribute(prop, value[prop]);
        }
        return newObject;
    }
    decode(model) {
      return Object.keys(model.cells).map(
        (iCell)=>{
          const currentCell = model.getCell(iCell);
          return (currentCell.value !== undefined)? currentCell : null;
        }
      ).filter((item)=> (item !== null));
    }
}

class GraphX {
  constructor(container){
            if (!mxClient.isBrowserSupported()) {
                  return mxUtils.error('Browser is not supported!', 200, false);
            } 
      mxEvent.disableContextMenu(container);
      this._graph = new mxGraph(container);
      this._graph.setConnectable(true);
      this._graph.setAllowDanglingEdges(false);
      new mxRubberband(this._graph); // Enables rubberband selection

      this.labelDisplayOveride();
      this.styling();
  }
  
  labelDisplayOveride() { // Overrides method to provide a cell label in the display
    this._graph.convertValueToString = (cell)=> {
      if (mxUtils.isNode(cell.value)) {
        if (cell.value.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'object') {
          const name = cell.getAttribute('name', '');
          return name;
        }
      }
      return '';
    };
  }
  
  styling() {
    // Creates the default style for vertices
    let style = [];
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_SHAPE] = mxConstants.SHAPE_RECTANGLE;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_PERIMETER] = mxPerimeter.RectanglePerimeter;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR] = 'gray';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_ROUNDED] = true;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FILLCOLOR] = '#EEEEEE';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_GRADIENTCOLOR] = 'white';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTCOLOR] = 'black';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_ALIGN] = mxConstants.ALIGN_CENTER;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_VERTICAL_ALIGN] = mxConstants.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTSIZE] = '12';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTSTYLE] = 1;
    this._graph.getStylesheet().putDefaultVertexStyle(style);

    // Creates the default style for edges
    style = this._graph.getStylesheet().getDefaultEdgeStyle();
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_STROKECOLOR] = '#0C0C0C';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_LABEL_BACKGROUNDCOLOR] = 'white';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_EDGE] = mxEdgeStyle.ElbowConnector;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_ROUNDED] = true;
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTCOLOR] = 'black';
    style[mxConstants.STYLE_FONTSIZE] = '10';
    this._graph.getStylesheet().putDefaultEdgeStyle(style);
  }
  
  getJsonModel(){
      const encoder = new JsonCodec();
      const jsonModel = encoder.decode(this._graph.getModel());
      return {
        "graph": jsonModel
      }
  }
  
  render(dataModel) {
        const jsonEncoder = new JsonCodec();
    
        this._vertices = {};
        this._dataModel = dataModel;
    
                const parent = this._graph.getDefaultParent();
                this._graph.getModel().beginUpdate(); // Adds cells to the model in a single step
                try {
          
          this._dataModel.graph.map(
            (node)=> {
                if(node.value) {
                  if(typeof node.value === "object") {
                       const xmlNode = jsonEncoder.encode(node.value);
                       this._vertices[node.id] = this._graph.insertVertex(parent, null, xmlNode, node.geometry.x, node.geometry.y, node.geometry.width, node.geometry.height);
                  } else if(node.value === "Edge") {
                       this._graph.insertEdge(parent, null, 'Edge', this._vertices[node.source],  this._vertices[node.target])
                  }
                }
            }
          );
          
                } finally {
                    this._graph.getModel().endUpdate(); // Updates the display
        }
  }  
}

/******************************************************************
Demo
******************************************************************/

const graphX = new GraphX(document.getElementById('graphContainer'));

document.getElementById('buttons').appendChild(mxUtils.button('From JSON', () => {
  const dataModel = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('from').innerHTML);
  graphX.render(dataModel);
}));

document.getElementById('buttons').appendChild(mxUtils.button('To JSON', () => {
  const jsonNodes = graphX.getJsonModel();
  document.getElementById('to').innerHTML = `<pre>${syntaxHighlight(stringifyWithoutCircular(jsonNodes))}</pre>`;
}));


/******************************************
Utils
********************************************/

function stringifyWithoutCircular(json){
  return JSON.stringify(
      json,
      ( key, value) => {
        if((key === 'parent' || key == 'source' || key == 'target') && value !== null) { 
          return value.id;
        } else if(key === 'value' && value !== null && value.localName) {
          let results = {};
          Object.keys(value.attributes).forEach(
            (attrKey)=>{
              const attribute = value.attributes[attrKey];
              results[attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
            }
          )
          return results;
        }
        return value;
      },
      4
  );
}

function syntaxHighlight(json) {
    json = json.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
    return json.replace(/("(\\u[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}|\\[^u]|[^\\"])*"(\s*:)?|\b(true|false|null)\b|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)/g, function (match) {
        var cls = 'number';
        if (/^"/.test(match)) {
            if (/:$/.test(match)) {
                cls = 'key';
            } else {
                cls = 'string';
            }
        } else if (/true|false/.test(match)) {
            cls = 'boolean';
        } else if (/null/.test(match)) {
            cls = 'null';
        }
        return '<span class="' + cls + '">' + match + '</span>';
    });
}
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to print the XML tree.

Here is how.

After you have a graph created in your typescript, there is an encoder class that you can use to get the XML representation of your basic graph. This serves as a basic step to start playing with the XML version of graphs and be able to render and serialize graphs.

```
  var encoder=new mxCodec();
  var node = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());
  var graphText=mxUtils.getXml(node);
  console.log(graphText)
```